# Global declaration of data structure with parameter

Tags: c++, global, declaration

I used LRU data structure in the main() such as following.

```
int main()
{
    load_parameter();
    cache::lru_cache<int, float> states_action0(STATES_NO_LRU);
    cache::lru_cache<int, float> states_action1(STATES_NO_LRU);   
    cache::lru_cache<int, float> states_action2(STATES_NO_LRU);
    .........

}
```

Note that STATES_NO_LRU is integer type variable which is loaded at the beginning of main().

However, I would like to move LRU data structure declaration to outside of main() to declare as global type.

At global declaration area, STATES_NO_LRU cannot be loaded.
In this case, how to deal with STATES_NO_LRU variable? 
In sum up, I would like to use lru_cache as a global data structure.

The source code (header part) of lru_cache is as follow

```
namespace cache {

template<typename key_t, typename value_t> class lru_cache { public:
        typedef typename std::pair<key_t, value_t> key_value_pair_t;
        typedef typename std::list<key_value_pair_t>::iterator list_iterator_t;

        lru_cache(size_t max_size) :
                _max_size(max_size) {
        }
```

Comment: This sounds like you are looking for the singleton design pattern.  It is a way to get the only instance of a class from anywhere in an application.

Comment: May I ask why you want to have global access to the lru_cache instance? Perhaps there is another way to solve the actual problem that does not involve a Singleton/global

Comment: I believe that there are good ways to solve the actual problem. Maybe I'm not an expert of C++, I bring out the idea which is global access of lru_cache.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you are looking for the singleton design pattern. It is a way to get the only instance of a class from anywhere in an application.

```
class Singleton {

private: 
    // Let's prevent any other instances of this object 
    // by making the constructor private
    Singleton() 
      : states_action0(STATES_NO_LRU) // Here we initialize states_action0 to STATES_NO_LRU
    {
    } 

    // This member will be accessible everywhere and only has one instance
    cache::lru_cache<int, float> states_action0; 
    // You could also put states_action1 here too.
public: 

    static Singleton& GetInstance() {
        static Singleton theSingleton;
        return theSingleton;
    }

    // For read-only access make this const
    lru_cache& GetCache() { 
        return states_action0; 
    }
};
```

Then you would use it like so anywhere in your application:

```
int main() {

    cache::lru_cache& states_action0 = Singleton::GetInstance().GetCache();
}
```

Comment: This does not solve the OP's problem. His statement is that STATES_NO_LRU is not known at compilation time, and is somehow fetched/computed at the start of his `main()` by `load_parameter();`

Answer (score 0):

Currently, when your cache object gets constructed you pass the relevant arguments. This means that you need to know what the arguments for its constructor should be when you create objects.
C++ initializes objects with static lifetime in 2 phases:

1. Static initialization (approximately: constants known at compile time, eg `int var= 42;` in namespace scope)
2. Dynamic initialization (approximately: some code needs to run to initialize them, eg `int var2 = foo()` in namespace scope)

What this basically means is that you have to do one of a few things:

### Create (*or initialize*) the object at a later time.

This is the approach which I would recommend to you. Those are actually 2 different solutions, one with pointers and one with late initialization of an already constructed object, but the both share the same idea so I'm bunching them in the same group. I'll explore only the pointer variant, the other one should be easy to follow.

What this would mean is to declare the `lru_cache` as a pointer, instead of by value. You would later dynamically create an object whenever you have loaded the needed data.

The Pointer solution would look something like this:

```
size_t load_parameter() {
    //do magic;
    return 42;
}

std::unique_ptr<lru_cache<int, float>> states_action0 = nullptr;

int main()
{
    size_t STATES_NO_LRU = load_parameter();
    states_action0 = std::make_unique<lru_cache<int, float>>(STATES_NO_LRU);
}
```

The late initialization solution would default-construct the `lru_cache` object, and implement a `lru_cache::initialize(size_t maxSize)` method to initialize the object.

### Create a factory-like function which will initialize the create the object

1. If we have not called `load_paramter()`, call it and store the results in a local static.
2. Construct an `lru_cache` object with the local static and return it.

I would strongly advise *against* such a solution. The time at which your loading would happen is implementation defined, and most probably would happen before main is called. It would look something like this:

```
size_t load_parameter() {
    //do magic;
    return 42;
}

lru_cache<int, float> cacheMaker()
{
    static size_t STATES_NO_LRU = -1;
    if (STATES_NO_LRU == -1)
    {
        STATES_NO_LRU = load_parameter();
    }
    return lru_cache<int, float>(STATES_NO_LRU);

}
lru_cache<int, float> states_action0 = cacheMaker();

int main()
{
}
```